# How I get titles in C# from Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello and sorry for my bad english, I'm working with C# Firebase I have a problem with retrieving data

My database is here;

```
[-] "Product":
   [-] "1":
        Brand: "Y Brand"
        BuyPrice: "1500$"
        Category: "Software"
        Id: "22"
        InStock: "15"
        Model: "x1500"
        SellPrice: "1600$"
        SerialNumber: "4564564654"
   [-] "2":
        Brand: "X Brand"
        BuyPrice: "1500$"
        Category: "Hardware"
        Id: "245"
        InStock: "45"
        Model: "x1600"
        SellPrice: "1700$"
        SerialNumber: "46848564654"
```

(I can't post images because I need 10 least reputation sorry)

this code retrieving datas in "Products/" + int
but I couldn't get Product title

```
try
{
    i++;
    con.resp = await con.client.GetAsync("Product/" + i);
    Product prdct = con.resp.ResultAs<Product>();

    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
    row["ID"] = prdct.Id;
    id = prdct.Id;
    row["Kategori"] = prdct.Category;
    row["Marka"] = prdct.Brand;
    row["Model"] = prdct.Model;
    row["Stok"] = prdct.InStock;
    row["Alış Fiyatı"] = prdct.BuyPrice;
    row["Satış Fiyatı"] = prdct.SellPrice;
    row["Seri Numarası"] = prdct.SerialNumber;
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
    tolerance = 0;
}
```

How I get this titles? Like in Access or Sql (Select ID from Product)

```
[-] "Product":
    [+] "1"
    [+] "2"
```

Comment: which is the Title field here?

Comment: In product 1 and 2

Comment: isn't that the value of `i` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem with this:

Database:

```cs
[-] "Products":
   [-] "All":
        Brand: "X Brand,Y Brand"
        BuyPrice: "1500$,1600$"
        Category: "Software,Hardware"
        Id: "22,23"
        InStock: "15,1675"
        Model: "x1500,x1600"
        SellPrice: "1600$,1700$"
        SerialNumber: "123,123"
```

I could get this datas and export to "string[] id, string[] brand" for every single child then code of below gets all datas under 1 second

```cs
Product prdct = con.resp.ResultAs<Product>();

getID = prdct.Id.Split(',');
getCategory = prdct.Category.Split(',');
getBrand = prdct.Brand.Split(',');
getModel = prdct.Model.Split(',');
getSellPrice = prdct.SellPrice.Split(',');
getBuyPrice = prdct.BuyPrice.Split(',');
getInStock = prdct.InStock.Split(',');
getSerialNumber = prdct.SerialNumber.Split(',');

try
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < GetID.Length; i++)
    {
        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();

        row["ID"] = GetID.GetValue(i);
        row["Kategori"] = getCategory.GetValue(i);
        row["Marka"] = GetBrand.GetValue(i);
        row["Model"] = GetModel.GetValue(i);
        row["Stok"] = GetInStock.GetValue(i);
        row["Alış Fiyatı"] = GetBuyPrice.GetValue(i);
        row["Satış Fiyatı"] = GetSellPrice.GetValue(i);
        row["Seri Numarası"] = getSerialNumber.GetValue(i);

        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
    }
}
```